# How to automatically mount airport connected hard drive as read only for a user account

Tags: network, wifi, hard-drive, airport

I have an external hard drive connected to my airport extreme. I am able to access the drive without any problems. However, I have user accounts set up for my two young children. I want to give access to the shared drive as read only for their accounts. I would like this read only setting to be automatic when these accounts log in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the drive mounted at login, drag the mounted volume to the Login Items in System Preferences → Users & Groups for the user that you want the volume auto mounting.

To set the permissions, Get Info (⌘I) on the drive and set the permissions in the Sharing & Permissions section.